# Does positive electricity run through neurons in the exact same way as it runs through copper?

Tags: neurophysiology

Does positive electricity moves in the exact same way as electric current moves through copper,silver and gold? From what I understand, electricity propagation in neurons is not linear as it is in a wire but rather in a cross-sectional way, moving forward little by little depolarizing the adjacent part ot the axon untill it gets to its destination.This is because the neuron cell membrane is made mainly by fat, and fat is consider an insulator. Besides, this is not an electric current but rather an ionic current, so atoms cannot move the way electrons do.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RNdvrkolW0M

Comment: Does [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/31069/how-does-a-change-in-the-potential-across-a-neurons-membrane-get-turned-into-a?rq=1) answer your question? Please search the site before asking a question. There's tons of information already here

Comment: @AliceD In other words, it is a polarization wave that propagates with a speed of sound in water (since it involves actual liquid flow). Whereas in copper we have a plasma wave, which propagates with the speed close to the speed of light.

Comment: @AliceD, I am not asking about the action potential in general, I am asking about the way charges move in the nerve fiber, and if they move just like they move in copper. I thought it was a specific question. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @Roger Vadim Thank you very much!, I have done some research on this topic but I cannot understand the exact difference between a plasma wave and a polarization wave. Would you mind to clarify please?